# Error on node js file to upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the problem here?

I have a node js file for file to upload action and another html file

File to upload.js

---

```
var formidable = require('formidable');

var http = require('http');

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

http.createServer(function(req, res){

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        console.log(files.filetoUpload.path);
    });
}).listen(3002);
```

---

fileUpload.html

```
<body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

        <input type="file" name="filetoUpload">
        <input type ="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>    
</body>
```

> Exception has occurred: Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'path'
>   of undefined
>       at d:\CUBIC\UI\asg\1\FileUpload.js:9:39
>       at IncomingForm. (d:\CUBIC\UI\asg\1\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:105:9)
>       at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>       at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (d:\CUBIC\UI\asg\1\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:553:8)
>       at Object.end (d:\CUBIC\UI\asg\1\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:239:12)
>       at IncomingMessage. (d:\CUBIC\UI\asg\1\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:130:30)
>       at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)

Comment: what do you get when you log `files` ?

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you that the property `path` for `files.filetoUpload` is not defined. Maybe `err` is populated? Have you check it yet?

Comment: In files.filetoUpload.path contains fakepath sample C:\\Users\\SYEDAY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ which does not exists in system.So that's why it is showing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `files.filetoupload.path)`, and it seems you've have coded this wrongly as, `files.filetoUpload.path)` (with U in uppercase).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> According to the specifications of HTML5, a file upload control should
>   not reveal the real local path to the file you have selected, if you
>   manipulate its value string with JavaScript. Instead, the string that
>   is returned by the script, which handles the file information is
>   C:\fakepath.
>
> This requirement is already implemented in Internet Explorer 8 - the
>   real path to the file will be shown only if the page that contains the
>   control is added to the trusted sites collection of the browser.

If you want to replace fake path use like this

That made sense; essentially the browser is feeding that lame C:\fakepath\ text in. Luckily all I needed to do was fix the issue by doing a simple string replace call:

```
// Change the node's value by removing the fake path
inputNode.value = fileInput.value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
```

You need to require path module in your upload.js file . Try using this in your code `var path=require('path');` and install the path module using `npm install path`

Try this code and you can see both the browser response and in response in terminal.

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/upload' && req.method === 'POST') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

        var key=files.upload[0];
        fs.readFileSync(key.path);
        console.log("path":key.path);
        console.log("File name":key.originalFilename);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields ,files:files.upload}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple" id="file-id"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

Run the server as `node app.js`  and upload the file using `http://localhost:8080` Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer here as I faced the same issue. Might help someone else.

I used `files.file.path` and it worked perfectly in Windows.

```
var formidable = require('formidable');

var http = require('http');

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

http.createServer(function(req, res){

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        console.log(files.file.path);
    });
}).listen(3002);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `files.fileupload.path` worked for me. Apparently formidable has changed the labeling a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure name attribute value of the input type and XXXXX (files.XXXXX.filepath) must be same. like i named as filetoupload

```
const formidable = require('formidable');
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
http.createServer((req,res) =>{
    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
        const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
            var newpath = 'C:/User/FOLDER_NAME' + files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
                res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
            res.end();
        });
        })
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'})
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
        res.write('<input type="submit">');
        res.write('</form>');
        return res.end("Over")
    }
}).listen(8080)
```